# Bootstrap - Calling a function ONLY when clicking the navbar-toggle button displays the menu items

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to call a JQuery function ONLY when clicking the navbar-toggle button for my navigation bar will show the menu items.

I do NOT want to call the JQuery function when the button hides my menu items.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can do so by checking whether `navbar` is **open** or **closed** like if it is **closed** perform what you want and if it is **open** do nothing.. Write a `click` event for `nav-bar` check whether closed class is present and then if yes do what you want or else do nothing and do not forget to toggle the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**add href of your navbar-toggle to menu item given id**

```
 $('.navbar-toggle').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //get menu selector
    var menu_selector = $(this).attr('href');       

    $(menu_selector).toggle(function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
           //this is show menu 
           //code here....

        } else {                                
          //this is hide menu
        }
    });
```